# Problema com javascript open

Tags: javascript

Estou utilizando o seguinte trecho de código:

```
window.open('provas-final.php','height=320, width=320', 'gl');
```

para abrir o arquivo "provas-final.php" e no próprio comando estou dizendo a largura e altura da janela que abrirá (320px), porém quando ela executa, abre uma janela totalmente contrária às dimensões que estou passando, conforme a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pesquisei na internet e vi exemplos iguais ao meu, alguém poderia me dizer o que está errado?

Answer (score 8):

Está faltando um argumento na sua chamada da função. A função espera `window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)` e você esta passando apenas 3 argumentos, então o seu segundo argumento `'height=320, width=320'` está sendo considerado como `name`. Faça da seguinte forma:

`window.open("home.php","_blank","height=320, width=320",false);`

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) - Se precisar de mais informações sobre a função `open()` consulte este link.

Comment: Opa, funcionou, valeu mesmo! Outra duvida, tem como fazer a janela abrir no centro da pagina? ela está abrindo no canto superior esquerdo..

Comment: Da uma olhada no link que coloquei no final da resposta, lá tem todos specs que você pode usar... Nesse caso, defina um `left` e um `top` para centralizar a janela.

Comment: Ganhou meu +1 por ser a resposta correta (apesar de usar justo o [w3schools](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/692) como referência com tanta fonte boa de informação na internet :P )

Comment: Problemas simples, soluções simples @Bacco... Eu so queria ver todos argumentos que o `open()` recebe xD

Comment: EU ja vi ele, o problema é que gostaria de definir um center para qualquer monitor, se eu definir um left e um top vai ficar desproporcional de acordo com o monitor utilizado

Comment: Aí já vai ser o caso de usar um window.moveTo(); com as ( coordenadas da tela - as da janela ) / 2 aproximadamente, mas é uma questão bem diferente.

Comment: Ok ,valeu gente! se eu soubesse como, dava +1 pra vcs

Comment: @Matheus Se a resposta do Daniel resolveu, vc pode clicar no "v" verdinho do lado dela. Você pode votar nas respostas tambem, e mais uma série de coisas à medida que ganhar mais pontos de reputação no site. Sugestão de leitura: [FAQ da Comunidade](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/699)

Comment: Se vcs quiserem eu adiciono na resposta depois, mas fiz um esqueminha pra você conseguir centralizar a janela por enquanto...

var widthWindow = 320;
 var heightWindow = 320;
 var leftWindow = ((screen.width/2) - (widthWindow/2));
 var topWindow = ((screen.height/2) - (heightWindow/2));
 var specs = "width="+widthWindow+",height="+heightWindow+",top="+topWindow+",left="+leftWindow;

 window.open("home.php","_blank",specs,false);
... Acho que isso não funciona se a pessoa tiver um setup com dois monitores, mas no momento estou só com um e não deu pra testar...

Comment: @MatheusLuz Por favor, se a resposta realmente resolveu seu problema, marque-a como correta para a questão ser dada como solucionada.